# "Connection" to Darmstadt but tickets only to Frankfurt. What transportation can I take to Darmstadt and how do I prove it's paid for?

Tags: trains, germany, deutsche-bahn

Ordering paper tickets from Bahn.DE, an e-mail confirmation said:

[image: E-mail confirmation]

> Your connection:
>   28.11.2017: London St. Pancras I 15:04 - Hauptbahnhof, Darmstadt 22:01
>
> Tickets:
>   Einfache Fahrt, Sparpreis Europa, 2. Kl., 1 Erw., London S Pancras In/Frankfurt(M)Flogh.#
>   Fare: 90,90 EUR
>
> Seat reservations:

(and then continues with seat reservation details)

The tickets only go to Frankfurt but the connection goes to Darmstadt.  What do I present in lieu of a ticket between Frankfurt and Darmstadt, and what modes of transportation am I entitled to for this segment?  Do I just show the e-mail reservation?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Looking on bahn.de for this trip, it seems you take a bus from Frankfurt Airport to Darmstadt.

It says "normal (international) tickets not valid , Subject to supplement", so (I am not sure but) it looks like you might need to pay for that separately.

You say you ordered paper tickets, so if you have not received them yet, it might become clearer upon reading them.

[image: screenshot of bahn.de]

---

The bus is called [*AirLiner Direkt*](https://www.rmv.de/en/Fahrkarten/Die_richtige_Fahrkarte/Fahrkarten_im_Ueberblick/Lokale_Fahrkartenangebote/42686/AirLiner_Darmstadt_Flughafen_Frankfurt.html) and starts here:

> Frankfurt airport: Terminal 1 (Bus stop 14), Gate 3 und Terminal 2

You can find the timetable and prices PDF (in German and English) [here](https://www.rmv.de/linkableblob/en/65908-108800/data/AirLiner_Direktbus_Darmstadt_Frankfurt_Flughafen.pdf). A single one-way trip for an adult costs 8.60 Euros and can be payed in the bus in cash or at a machine, where you can pay with Maestro (and maybe credit card).

Comment: The e-mail confirmation doesn't say anything about the supplement.  I have the paper tickets; the paper tickets do not mention Darmstadt at all.  Looks like that when you buy London-Darmstadt through bahn.de they essentially only sell London-Frankfurt, and how people get to Darmstadt is their own problem?

Comment: Yeah, it's not clear to me either.

Comment: @gerrit The airport transfer bus that runs to Darmstadt Hauptbahnhof from Frankfurt Flughafen is operated by a private company that is not part of Bahn, and the local transportation tickets don't work without a surcharge either. DB cannot sell tickets for those. You have to buy a bus ticket, and the _connection_ part of your paper is only for your information to list the overall connection details, so you know what to take. (This bus is not even free for BC100 owners, which is the _every train is free for a year_ ticket for 4k Euros).

Comment: @simbabque DB serves Darmstadt.  I've asked for a ticket to Darmstadt.  They won't sell me a ticket to Darmstadt.  That's poor service.  Anyway, the train from London to Brussels is not run by Bahn either, but they can still serve a ticket, so the fact that something is not run by Bahn is not the root of the problem here.  I did try to ask the travel agent (this is work travel or I wouldn't have used one) to search for a no-buses-connection but they were unable to figure out how (although I explained it to them).

Comment: @gerrit there are ICEs and intercity I still going there. I've taken both, and the bus. Sometimes you end up with an ICE that only goes through Flughafen. Then you are stuck with this.

Comment: ICE 19 does goes to Hbf.  Looks like I'm cheaper off taking the S-Bahn from Hbf if I can get away with staying on the train to Hbf (I probably am but I'm aware I'm not supposed to).  On the way back I have a train ticket starting at Darmstadt.  I do think it's dishonest of DB to offer an itinerary to a location they service, but then deliver a ticket for only part of the journey.

Comment: @gerrit DB offers you two options: Going by bus the last part from Frankfurt Flughafen to Darmstadt (which is faster), or going all the way by train, requiring a detour to Frankfurt Hbf and back to Darmstadt, which takes longer, but allows you to use a train for the entire itinerary. If you bought the train/bus combination online, you are several times during the booking process being adviced that the presented price is only a partial fare for London to Frankfurt Flughafen and that you need to buy a separate, additional ticket for the bus.

Comment: @Tor-EinarJarnbjo I am travelling for work and my employer does not allow us to book our own travel. Employer requires us to book every trip through the travel agent, and they're incompetent; they tell me the ticket is valid for travel to Darmstadt. I told them that by selecting advanced travel options, then deselecting buses, it's possible to book a train-only journey, but they were unable.

Comment: @gerrit Then blame your incompetent travel agency and not German Railways. The DB route planner is just trying to offer you a more convenient (or at least faster) connection at the cost of not being able to sell you a ticket for the entire journey. Your ticket is only valid to Frankfurt Flughafen. Wether you go by bus or by train, you will need a new ticket from Frankfurt Flughafen to Darmstadt.

Comment: @gerrit Maybe you can convince your travel agent if you show them the [pop-up that appears](https://i.imgur.com/39u1rF7.png) on clicking on the "DB+abroad part" link, which explicitly states that the Frankfurt-Darmstadt leg is *not* included in the ticket price. I agree that they should flag this up a bit more prominently in the fare selection screen.

Comment: @Pont Right.  Too late now as the tickets are issued. Impressive the travel agent has managed to miss that.  I'll just have to buy tickets for the last bit myself then (bus or S-Bahn) and ask my employer for reimbursement pointing out the agent was unable to book this in advance.

Comment: @simbabque Thanks for making that edit, it's very useful.

Comment: @gerrit the bus being faster, and the regional train or IC not being the most comfortable, I think you will want to go by bus It drops you off directly in front of the train station, which saves you a bunch of stairs where there are no escalators. You do not want to go by Taxi from the airport to your company or hotel in Darmstadt as that will likely cost somewhere between 50 and 100 Euros.

Comment: @simbabque By bus I arrive only 20 minutes earlier, I do prefer S-Bahn over bus, I suspect I can get away with staying on the ICE until Hbf rather than getting off at Flughafen, I could grab some food in central Frankfurt on the way which is surely better than at the airport (I remember big distances to/from Fernbahnhof), I'm not considering any taxi.

Comment: @gerrit there are fastfood stalls right in the central station. The regional trains do not have tables though. Staying on should not be a huge problem. They usually don't check tickets after every stop, especially not in a full train, and they don't recheck unless they switch their staff.

Comment: @gerrit With some skill, you can get away travelling on most German trains without a ticket. It is not *that* difficult to avoid the ticket inspectors, if there are any at all aboard the train. For your information: Fare evation is a criminal offence and punishable with a fine or up to one year imprisonment (German criminal code, StGB § 265a). If you are not a repeating offender, most transport companies don't bother with the prosecution, but leave it with a double fare or at least 60€ penalty.

Comment: @Tor-EinarJarnbjo I've never heard of people getting fined for accidentally missing their stop, in particular when the next stop is 5 minutes away.

Comment: @gerrit: it depends on the conductor. I know someone who was fined 40€ because he took a train at 8:50 although his ticket was only valid after 9:00 (Länderticket).